# Python: Sorting a file

Tags: python, sorting

I've got a data of twitter log and I have to sort the file to show 
each user's retweeted tweet ranking.

here's the code.

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('hoge_qdata.tsv','r', 'utf-8') as tweets:
    tweet_list = tweets.readlines()

tweet_list.pop(0)

facul={}
for t in tweet_list:
    t=t.split('\t')
    if not t[0] in facul:
        facul[t[0]]=[]
    facul[t[0]].append(t)
    t[-2]= int(t[-2])

def cmp_retweet(a,b):
    if a[-2]<b[-2]:
        return 1
    if a[-2]>b[-2]:
        return -1
    return 0

for f in sorted(facul.keys()):
    facul[f].sort(cmp = cmp_retweet)
    print ('[%s]' %(f))
    for t in facul[f][:5]:
        print ('%d:%s:%s' %(t[-2], t[2], t[-1].strip()))
```

I almost got the right answer but I have to make it so that it would not 
show the tweets that are not retweeted..

this is the answer I should get(this is just a section I have a trouble with):

```
[jin_nkzw]
325:46936947935035392:RT @shimshamshimmy: SFCの学生と教職員の方へ、安否確認に協力してください。SFC-SFSで伝えてください。 https://vu8.sfc.keio.ac.jp/sfc-sfs/
```

but this is what I get...

```
[jin_nkzw]
325:46936947935035392:RT @shimshamshimmy: SFCの学生と教職員の方へ、安否確認に協力してください。SFC-SFSで伝えてください。 https://vu8.sfc.keio.ac.jp/sfc-sfs/
0:8356641661:麹町のNICTで会議。ビルの目の前に、今朝のテレビでやってた「ふゆざくら」が咲いていた。
0:4979124091:@sfc_orf リンゴの木は会場俯瞰図(断面)からタッチパネルが生えているということで、「断面の触覚」という名前が浮かびました。「断面の触感」と言葉が近すぎて誤植と思われますかね〜
0:11422290558:いまになって、@who_meさんをフォローしていなかったことに気づく
0:7940726154:秋葉原で1000円程度で手配できるおいしいお弁当といったら何でしょう？
```

the format is.. 
number of retweet:id:content

I can't figure how to erase those tweets.

Comment: can't you just check if `t[-2] == 0` before printing?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume this would do the trick:

```
for t in tweet_list:
    t=t.split('\t')
    t[-2]= int(t[-2])   # Move this up here.
    if t[-2] <= 0:      # Check the retweet value.
        continue        # If it's 0 or less, skip this tweet completely.
    if not t[0] in facul:
        facul[t[0]]=[]
    facul[t[0]].append(t)
```

Or if you want to store the tweets, but not print them:

```
    for t in facul[f][:5]:
        if t[-2] > 0:
            print ('%d:%s:%s' %(t[-2], t[2], t[-1].strip()))
```

Comment: A useful tip: instead of constructs like `if not k in d: d[k] = []`, use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: somehow I got errors saying
File "kadai3-2.py", line 29, in <module>
    print '%d:%s:%s' %(t[-2], t[2], t[-1].encode('utf-8').strip())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)

what happened here?? what should do to fix this?

Comment: It looks like one of the tweets you're trying to print has characters that can't be decoded.

Comment: I tried to use 
for t in facul[f][:5]:
  print '%d:%s:%s' %(t[-2], t[2], t[-1].encode('utf-8').strip())
but it didn't work... is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: It's hard to say without actually seeing the characters you're trying to print. This might qualify as a totally different question.